# VBA Click on MS Access application button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an ms access application which has some button. I would like to do an automation with it using vba from excel and click on these button to record the behaviour.

```
Private Sub devButton_Click()
    Dim appAccess As Object

    'create new access object
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    'open the acces project
    Call appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase( _
    "\\C:\MsAccess\Application.accdb")
    appAccess.Visible = True
    
    With appAccess
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       .Button("Command204").Click
        End With

End Sub
```

[image]

However, I am getting an error when executing the button click. Can some one help?

Comment: What is the error and on which line?

Comment: remove the `\\ ` from your path. That is not a valid path. `\\C:\MsAccess\Application.accdb`

Comment: Also the application object doesn't have a `.Button` object. You have multiple problems here.

Comment: Why do you need to use Excel to automate Access?

Comment: I couldn't find another application which can automate Access.

Comment: A VBScript or bat file can do some automation. Why do you need to automate Access? Why do you need to call this procedure from outside Access.

Comment: This is a client application for getting different reports from each of the button. The front end is access. I am a software tester and I need to automate this process to easy my job. I chose excel as I can write the testing status (pass/fail) after each test in a report format.

Comment: So the end user really has no need for this automation?

Comment: true. This is just to avoiding same tasks which can take 1 hr of my time everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. form is set in Access to open by default when database opens
2. Access form button Click procedure is not defined as Private

```
Private Sub devButton_Click()
    Dim appAccess As Object

    'create new access object
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    'open the acces project
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\MsAccess\Application.accdb")
    appAccess.Visible = True
    
    With appAccess
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Forms!formname.Command204_Click
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the button click on the access is defined as private

Private Sub Command204_Click()

Comment: Remove Private keyword.

Comment: I cannot change the source code of the application unfortunately. Is there any way to get the controller if its private?

Comment: I would have indicated so if I was aware of one.